# Convert-SPWebApplication to ADFS

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, adfs

I am wondering if I can rerun Convert-SPWebApplication on a web app that has already been converted to ADFS, using the same command. We have multiple content databases and an NTLM version of a content database was restored to our UAT instance, overwriting the ADSF version. I want to convert it to ADFS again without having to use Move-SPUser on the specific site collection database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to re-run Convert-SPWebApplication on the web app. However, I first had to remove the trusted identity token issuer and trusted root authority:

```
Remove-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer -Identity "ADFS" 
Remove-SPTrustedRootAuthority -Identity "ADFS Token Signing Cert Parent"
```

and then re-add it.

Next, I ran Convert-SPWebApplication using a database switch to point to the specific database:

```
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication -Identity "https://web.app.url"
$tp= Get-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer "ADFS"
$skipList = "D:\ADFS\SkipList.csv"

$database = Get-SPContentDatabase -Identity "Content Database Name"

Convert-SPWebApplication -id $wa -To CLAIMS-TRUSTED-DEFAULT -From CLAIMS-WINDOWS -database $database -TrustedProvider $tp -SourceSkipList $skipList -RetainPermissions
```

I tried to run it without removing the trusted identity token issuer but it kept erring out.